# Strange infinite loop on mediawiki-gateway gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Code is trapped in an infinite loop right on the REXML line. I've debugged and strangely, that line of code is run again and again, forever. Doesn't make any sense.

This method is from the mediawiki-gateway gem https://github.com/jpatokal/mediawiki-gateway

```
# Get a list of pages with matching content in given namespaces
#
# [key] Search key
# [namespaces] Array of namespace names to search (defaults to main only)
# [limit] Maximum number of hits to ask for (defaults to 500; note that Wikimedia Foundation wikis allow only 50 for normal users)
#
# Returns array of page titles (empty if no matches)
def search(key, namespaces=nil, limit=@options[:limit])
  titles = []
  offset = nil
  in_progress = true

  form_data = { 'action' => 'query',
    'list' => 'search',
    'srwhat' => 'text',
    'srsearch' => key,
    'srlimit' => limit
  }
  if namespaces
    namespaces = [ namespaces ] unless namespaces.kind_of? Array
    form_data['srnamespace'] = namespaces.map! do |ns| namespaces_by_prefix[ns] end.join('|')
  end
  begin
    form_data['sroffset'] = offset if offset
    res, offset = make_api_request(form_data, '//query-continue/search/@sroffset')
    titles += REXML::XPath.match(res, "//p").map { |x| x.attributes["title"] }
  end while offset
  titles
end
```

The steps to reproduce are as follow

Open an irb and code

```
require 'media_wiki'

options = {
      :limit => 50
}
@mw = MediaWiki::Gateway.new('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', options)
@mw.search('Strange Loop')
```

Unfortunately, it will never end.

Comment: I just ran your example and failed to recreate the bug. `@mw.search('Strange Loop')` returned an Array of 1008 items (it took a bit, I thought it was stalled for a moment). Ruby 1.9.3p194, mediawiki-gateway 0.5.1

Comment: Querying for Brazil and a debugger problem lead me to this conclusion. You are right. The :limit param refers to the chunck size it loads at a time. But if you have a 1000 results, it's gonna call it 200 times with a limit of 50 per chunk. I've just forked the gem to add some especifics behaviors I need for my app. Thank you.